# How do I do a monadic bind to an async function?

Tags: c#, async-await, bind, monads

Consider this basic implementation of the maybe monad:

```
public class Maybe<T>
{
    private readonly T value;

    private Maybe(bool hasValue, T value) : this(hasValue) => this.value = value;

    private Maybe(bool hasValue) => HasValue = hasValue;

    public bool HasValue {get;}

    public T Value => HasValue ? value : throw new InvalidOperationException();

    public static Maybe<T> None {get;} = new Maybe<T>(false);

    public static Maybe<T> Some(T value) => new Maybe<T>(true, value);

    public Maybe<U> Bind<U>(Func<T, Maybe<U>> f) => HasValue ? f(value) : Maybe<U>.None;
}
```

Its purpose is to handle a chain of functions returning optional values in a clean way:

```
var client = Maybe<int>.Some(1)
    .Bind(orderId => GetOrder(orderId))
    .Bind(order => GetClient(order.ClientId));
Console.WriteLine(client);
```

In the above case both `GetOrder` and `GetClient` return a `Maybe<T>`, but handling of the `None` case is hidden inside `Bind`. So far so good.

But how would I bind a `Maybe<T>` to an `async` function, i.e. a function returning `Task<Maybe<T>>` instead? For instance the following code fails with compiler errors, because `Bind` expects a `Func<T, Maybe<U>>` rather than a `Func<T, Task<Maybe<U>>>`:

```
var client = Maybe<int>.Some(1)
    .Bind(orderId => GetOrderAsync(orderId))
    .Bind(order => GetClientAsync(order.ClientId));
Console.WriteLine(client);
```

I tried to `await` the `Task` inside the lambda passed to `Bind`, but that forced me to add an overload of `Bind` that accepts functions returning a `Task`:

```
public Maybe<U> Bind<U>(Func<T, Task<Maybe<U>>> f) 
    => HasValue ? f(value).Result : Maybe<U>.None;
```

As you can see, the code is not running `async` anymore, and instead blocks with `Result`. Meh.

Second try was to `await` the task inside the new `Bind`:

```
public async Task<Maybe<U>> Bind<U>(Func<T, Task<Maybe<U>>> f) 
    => HasValue ? await f(value) : Maybe<U>.None;
```

But now `Bind` has to wrap the `Maybe<T>` in a `Task` and chaining will look ugly:

```
var asyncClient = await (await Maybe<int>.Some(2)
    .Bind(orderId => GetOrderAsync(orderId)))
    .Bind(order => GetClientAsync(order.ClientId));
```

Is there a nicer solution to this?

I created a [fully working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gbpHEv), in case I missed some details in the explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I found a good solution. The idea is to extend `Task<Maybe<T>>` with two `Bind` functions that basically forward the await to the first function in the `Maybe<T>` chain:

```
public static class TaskExtensions 
{
    public static async Task<Maybe<U>> Bind<T, U>(
        this Task<Maybe<T>> task, Func<T, Maybe<U>> f) 
        => (await task).Bind(f);

    public static async Task<Maybe<U>> Bind<T, U>(
        this Task<Maybe<T>> task, Func<T, Task<Maybe<U>>> f) 
        => await (await task).Bind(f);
}
```

Armed with these we can bind functions to `Maybe<T>` tasks that either return a `Maybe<T>` directly or another `Maybe<T>` task:

```
// Notice how we only have to await once at the top.
var asyncClient = await Maybe<int>.Some(2)
    .Bind(orderId => GetOrderAsync(orderId))
    .Bind(order => GetClientAsync(order.ClientId));
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kekp0S